# Detecting if java is installed and enabled with javascript

Tags: javascript, java

I need to be able to determine if a user has Java installed and enabled through JavaScript.  The 1st requirement is easily done, I'm using the deployment toolkit script:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html

However, in the situation where a user has java installed, but they have disabled it (NOT disabled support in the browser, but disabled via the java control panel in Windows), the installed versions still show up in calls to `deployJava.getJREs()`.  Is there any way to detect versions of Java that are both installed AND enabled using JavaScript?

Comment: @John, i think what the op wants is a way to detect browser version of JAVA with javascript

Comment: try the good old run some Java, try to connect to javascript through java then detect whether that connection is open.

Comment: @Neal, I've already managed to get a list of java versions available.  I just need to be able to detect when those versions have been disabled.  Maybe that's not possible, I kind of figured it was a long shot.  The reason I need this is so I can determine if I can successfully embed an applet into the page.

Comment: @John - That's a cute phrase, but how does it apply here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Detect if an applet is ready](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0176.html) at Real's HowTo.  AFAIU that should only be true once the applet is loaded and started.

There are also ways to call applet methods directly from JavaScript, if the first technique fails, you might look to that in order to ensure the applet is both loaded and working.

---

Another approach is to set a meta-refresh redirect element in the HTML, then have the applet call a JS to **cancel** the redirect if it loads successfully.  The idea would be to set the `href` of the redirect to point to a page with words to the effect 'Sorry, our applet failed to load within NN seconds.  Click -here- for support.'