# Java version and installation check doesn't work

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, java-web-start

I am using javascript in a webpage to check if java and java web start is installed on the computer.Like this

```
      var javawsInstalled = 0;
      var javaws150Installed = 0;
      isIE = "false";

      if (navigator.mimeTypes && navigator.mimeTypes.length) {
         x = navigator.mimeTypes['application/x-java-jnlp-file'];
         if (x){
            javawsInstalled = 1;
            javaws150Installed = 1;
         } 
      } else {
         isIE = "true";
      }
      console.log("javawsInstalled: " + javawsInstalled)
      console.log("javaws150Installed: "+ javaws150Installed)
      console.log("is IE" + isIE)
```

before this there is  code

```
<SCRIPT language=VBScript>
          on error resume next
          If isIE = "true" Then
            If Not(IsObject(CreateObject("JavaWebStart.IsInstalled"))) Then
                  javawsInstalled = 0
            Else
                  javawsInstalled = 1
            End If

            If Not(IsObject(CreateObject("JavaWebStart.isInstalled.1.6.0.0"))) Then
                  javaws150Installed = 0
            Else
                  javaws150Installed = 1
            End If  
          End If
</SCRIPT>
```

However it doesn't seem to work perfectly on all browsers and all java versions ,for instance, it will dispay the below in console when Java 7 update 15 is installed.

```
javawsInstalled: 0 index_cn.jsp:27
javaws150Installed: 0 index_cn.jsp:28
is IEfalse
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [detect java not installed and provide a link from Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273892/detect-java-not-installed-and-provide-a-link-from-javascript)

Comment: *`If Not(IsObject(CreateObject("JavaWebStart.IsInstalled"))) Then`* change that first `i` of `IsInstalled` to lower case - e.g. `If Not(IsObject(CreateObject("JavaWebStart.isInstalled"))) Then`..