# Information about Java plugins (in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, java, browser, plugins

I need the following information about my Java plugins in Firefox (see picture):

**plugin 'Java (TM)':**

- Is the plugins 'Java (TM)' installed?
- Which version of this plugin is installed?
- What is the status of this plugin: "Immer aktivieren", "Nachfragen, ob aktiviert werden soll", "Nie aktivieren", ...?

**plugin 'Java Deployment Toolkit':**

- Is the plugins 'Java Deployment Toolkit' installed?
- Which version of this plugin is installed?
- What is the status of this plugin: "Immer aktivieren", "Nachfragen, ob aktiviert werden soll", "Nie aktivieren", ...?

How can I get this information with **JavaScript**?

Thank's for yor hints, Thomas

[image]

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to ask the browser if it's installed. You could look at the following though http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746663/detecting-if-java-is-installed-and-enabled-with-javascript

Comment: Maybe this will help you: [detect-version-of-java-using-javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/440160/detect-version-of-java-using-javascript)